# Symfony 3.4, one to many associations for email, form says invalid input

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have an Entity and a Form for that entity, that accepts multiple administrative emails:

```
    ->add(
        'administrativeEmails',
        EntityType::class,
        [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Merchant\AdministrativeEmailContact',
            'label' => 'Emails Administrativos',
            'choice_label' => 'email',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'multiple' => true,
        ]
    )
```

In my FormType class.

However, when I try to save the form with multiple emails, it says that the form is invalid. Which makes sense, because I'm telling Doctrine / Symfony that the entity should exist.

But what I need to do, is to enter custom emails and add them to an association. Of course it would be easier to add a comma-separated field with values but I think this is more "correct" for queries.

Payload goes like this:

[image]

What would be the best way to prevent the form error? I need to add the entities if they don't exist

Comment: If you want to add multiple emails that do not exist yet, look into Symfony form collections: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: @Marleen thanks, wasn't thaaaaaat easy but I came with a solution using Select2 and that guide

Answer (score 0):

in my project it worked fine try to change your code to be like this

```
->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => function(Category $category) {
                    return $category->getName();
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une categorie'
            ])
```

Comment: Yes but I think that your Categories already exists and are defined in the database. The emails are not defined in the DB

Comment: Yes the categories already exists in the database